# How to Obtain New Image Filename

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I plan on storing images on file system using ImageResizer and storing the image URLs in a DB. I have gone through the API again and again but can find no obvious way of obtaining the newly-created filename to include in the DB URL:

```
foreach (string fileKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];
    if (file.ContentLength <= 0) continue; //Skip unused file controls.

    ImageJob i = new ImageJob(file, "~/eventimages/<guid>_<filename:A-Za-z0-9>.<ext>", 
        new ResizeSettings("width=200&height=133&format=jpg&crop=auto"));
    i.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: http://nathanaeljones.github.com/resizer-docs/doxygen/class_image_resizer_1_1_image_job.html

```
string  FinalPath [get, set]
        Contains the final physical path to the image (if 'dest' was a path - null otherwise)
```

Considering `dest` was a path for you, I imagine `FinalPath` contains what you need.